# get image from sdcard base on filename from sqlite and display in gridview

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

try to get image from sdcard and display in gridview, data image filename from sqlite. Before display i want to check image filename exist in sqlite

Following is the code I have gotten so far:-

/*******sqlitE******/

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_IMGNAME + " FROM " + TABLE_PLANTASKIMG + " WHERE project_planner_task_id='" + plantaskid + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMGNAME)));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
```

/**** end sqlite ****/

```
file_name_in_db = db.getImgTask(pptaskid);listFile = file.listFiles();
        // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
        FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
        // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
        FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {


            for(int j=0; j<file_name_in_db.length;i++){
                if(file_name_in_db[j].equals(FileNameStrings[i])){

          // Get the path of the image file
            FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d(TAG,"filepathstring:"+FilePathStrings);
            // Get the name image file
            FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
            Log.d(TAG,"FileNameStrings:"+FileNameStrings);

                }
            }
        }
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, FilePathStrings, file_name_in_db);
    // Set the LazyAdapter to the GridView
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

my problem is above code not working for me on checking image  filename from sqlite with image filename in sdcard.

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: my issue on checking filename from sqlite with image in folder

Comment: if the above for loop is executing fine and app is running on marshmallow device, then issue might be runtime permissions .. check it once...